# CoreAudio: Why does ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL return 0xFFFFFFCE?

Tags: iphone, macos, core-audio

It's meant to return an `OSType`, but instead I'm just getting -50. Does anyone have any idea what error this represents? I can't find it anywhere.

A code snippet for context (the error is so ambiguous I don't know what snippet to paste, here's pretty much everything):

```
ExtAudioFileRef cafFile;
AudioStreamBasicDescription cafDesc;

cafDesc.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
cafDesc.mBytesPerFrame = 4;
cafDesc.mBytesPerPacket = 4;
cafDesc.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
cafDesc.mFormatFlags = 0;
cafDesc.mFormatID = 'ima4';
cafDesc.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
cafDesc.mReserved = 0;
cafDesc.mSampleRate = 44100;

OSType status = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(
                   fileURL,                    // inURL
                   'caff',                     // inFileType
                   &cafDesc,                   // inStreamDesc
                   NULL,                       // inChannelLayout
                   kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,  // inFlags
                   &cafFile                    // outExtAudioFile
                   );    // returns 0xFFFFFFCE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL()`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL) returns an `OSStatus`, not an `OSType`.  See the file `MacErrors.h` for the various error codes.  In this case, -50 is `paramErr` (error in user parameter list), so you're passing one or more of the parameters incorrectly to the function.